# Can we avoid getting a blank row at the end of txt file while exporting the date from sql query through ssis?

Tags: sql, ssis

My Scenario: I have a Scenario where I need to generate a text tab delimited file using SSIS, the source data is coming from SQL query.

Problem: I have generated the text clean text file but I am getting a empty row at the end of file, I need to remove that line, I checked my sql query results there are no blank rows in it. can anyone please suggest me what should I do?

Source Query:

```
SELECT  
    CASE 
              WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 2 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(D,-3,GETDATE()),126)))
              WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 3 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(D,-1,GETDATE()),126)))
              WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 4 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(D,-1,GETDATE()),126)))
              WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 5 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(D,-1,GETDATE()),126)))
              WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 6 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(D,-1,GETDATE()),126)))
            ELSE ''
          END AS [COB Date],
     LTRIM(RTRIM('1802'))  AS Branch,
     LTRIM(RTRIM(CIF)) AS [Client Id],
     LTRIM(RTRIM(CRM.[Limit ID])) AS [LIMIT ID],
     LTRIM(RTRIM([TRANSACTION])) AS [Account Id],
     CASE [DEMAND-TERM] WHEN 'DEMAND' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM('316')) ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM('319'))  END AS [Account Type],
     LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(DATE,CRM.[Start Date]))) AS  [Start Date],
     CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(LD.[TRANSACTION])) LIKE ('1%') THEN 
                                              CASE 
                                     WHEN  LTRIM(RTRIM(CRM.[Expiry Date])) = '22220222' AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 2 OR CRM.[Expiry Date] = '' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))))
                                     WHEN  LTRIM(RTRIM(CRM.[Expiry Date])) = '22220222' AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 3 OR CRM.[Expiry Date] = '' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))))
                                     WHEN  LTRIM(RTRIM(CRM.[Expiry Date])) = '22220222' AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 4 OR CRM.[Expiry Date] = '' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))))
                                     WHEN  LTRIM(RTRIM(CRM.[Expiry Date])) = '22220222' AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 5 OR CRM.[Expiry Date] = '' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))))
                                     WHEN  LTRIM(RTRIM(CRM.[Expiry Date])) = '22220222' AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 6 OR CRM.[Expiry Date] = '' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(DATEADD(DAY,3,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))))
                                     WHEN  LTRIM(RTRIM(CRM.[Expiry Date])) = '22220222' AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 7 OR CRM.[Expiry Date] = '' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(DATEADD(DAY,2,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))))
                                     WHEN  LTRIM(RTRIM(CRM.[Expiry Date])) = '22220222' AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 1 OR CRM.[Expiry Date] = '' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())))) 
                                ELSE CONVERT(DATE,CRM.[Expiry Date]) END ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(DATE,LD.[OUTSTANDING-MATURITY-DATE]))) END AS [Maturity Date],
     LTRIM(RTRIM(CCY)) AS [Account Currency],
     LTRIM(RTRIM(OUTSTANDING)) AS [Amount],
     LTRIM(RTRIM('D')) AS [Debit Credit],
     CASE  WHEN [CIF] = '100665' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM('286')) ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM('285')) END AS [Product Code]    
FROM  [LOAN.DETAIL] LD
LEFT JOIN t_CRM_MONTHLY_RPT_NY CRM
ON LD.[LIMIT-ID] = CRM.[Limit ID]
WHERE ([RM-AREA] = 'UHNN')
```

Destination file:
[image]

I need only 49 rows not 50 rows. 
How can I do this?

Comment: just for debugging, try changing your SQL to SELECT GETDATE() and see if you still have the blank line.  If you do, then it's SSIS, not your query inserting the blank row at the end.

Comment: Hi Beth,   I tried as you said but still creating empty line

Comment: The files that I am creating using SSIS are sending through FTP server to a Linux server

Comment: then there's nothing introducing it in your SSIS package, it could be your FTP or Linux server process adding it.  There may be a setting that could be changed there so it isn't introduced in the first place.